# show hide image in android

Tags: android

i have a code like this
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.correct);
newImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rwans);
newImg.setImageBitmap(bm);

but i want after a second, image should fade out or it display nothing or as previous state.
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294699/how-to-hide-image-after-a-second-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

post a delayed message to the `Handler` and do a `ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. To achieve the fade out effect you can use an Animation.