# how to hide image after a second in android

Tags: android

Is there any way to hide a image after a second or given time in android application?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

post a delayed message to a `Handler` that essentially does:

```
ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```